# Mocha / Chair - run test in multiple files

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a common test I want to run in multiple test files, I did some research and this is the suggested solution I found to include tests in a file:

**Directory Structure:**

```
|--test
   |--common
      |--common.js
   |--common_functions.js
   |--helpers.js
   |--registration.js
```

**common.js**

```
var helpers = require("../../services/helpers");
var chai = require("chai");
var expect = require("chai").expect;
chai.should();
chai.use(require("chai-things"));
var testData = require("../../config/testData");

  it('check if we are connected to local test db', function(done) {
      helpers.checkTestDB(function(err, result) {
          expect(err).to.equal(null);
          result.should.equal('This is the test DB');
          done();
      });
  });
```

**common_functions.js**

```
exports.importTest = function(name, path) {
    describe(name, function () {
        require(path);
    });
}
```

**helpers.js / registration.js**

```
...
var common_functions = require('./common_functions');
...
describe("Common Tests Import", function(){
  common_functions.importTest("checkDb",'./common/common');
});
```

The problem is that the test only runs on one of the two files, if I leave it in both it runs on helpers, if I comment out helpers, the registration one runs, is there a way to run it in each of these?

The reason being is that I'm setting the env variable in each file to use a test db, but there is a lot going on and in case it somehow changes I'd like it to run on each file separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do in `common.js` something similar to what you did in `common_functions.js`: *export* a function that calls `it`, rather than have `it` sit at the top level like you do now. So modify `common.js` to something like this:

```
var helpers = require("../../services/helpers");
var chai = require("chai");
var expect = require("chai").expect;
chai.should();
chai.use(require("chai-things"));
var testData = require("../../config/testData");

module.exports = function () {
  it('check if we are connected to local test db', function(done) {
      helpers.checkTestDB(function(err, result) {
          expect(err).to.equal(null);
          result.should.equal('This is the test DB');
          done();
      });
  });
};
```

Then you call this function after you import the module. so change `common_functions.js` to something like this:

```
exports.importTest = function(name, path) {
    describe(name, function () {
        // We call the function exported by the module.
        require(path)();
    });
}
```

Otherwise, the problem is that because CommonJS modules are singletons, then the `it` call in `common.js` will be executed once, *and only once*, when Node reads the file and creates the module in memory. Subsequent `require('./common/common')` calls won't execute the module's code again.